# 'circos' style plots with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, circos

Does anybody know if there's a way to make [circos-style](http://circos.ca) plots with `matplotlib` python package, or any other python library?  They don't have to be as nice looking as the example.

Comment: The nxviz package might have what you need: https://github.com/ericmjl/nxviz

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no direct functionality for this. If I were to create this functionality, I would use [polar plots](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/polar_scatter.html) as the starting point, then I would create a [transformation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/transforms_tutorial.html) to convert data positions along the circular axis to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Yann's idea is great.And more, circos is developed by Perl with GD and other modules, and then output SVG (or png). Python can also do this if you want to create new wheel :)

As I know if  you wanna circos style images (circular style) by matplotlib, you'd better write  raw python code directly :

1. learn basic SVG grammar
2. use python to generate the basic layout
3. design your image elements
4. computing and transforming your data coordinates; you'd better think it in polar coordinates (I did the same things but without open source.)
5. output your elements.

If you like, join circos's google group to discuss: http://groups.google.com/group/circos-data-visualization

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Biopython's module GenomeDiagram has similar functionality, although it is designed for plotting genomic data, but not any data, as in circos, and the output won't be that nice.